# Why the usage spikes?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, bandwidth, mobile-broadband

I have a Verizon wireless account with a phone and a wireless router. I have a 2 gig data plan - I do not use much bandwidth, as I use my computer for email, web, writing, and development, much less usage than overall usage watching video or whatnot. Usually, a few days before the end of the billing period, Verizon texts me saying that I am using 50% usage.

This past month, the 50% warning came right on time, a few days before the end of the billing period, but this time it was followed in quick succession by a 75% usage, then 90%, then overage. I have in the meantime been using low-bandwidth applications.

Is my bandwidth being pirated? Should I open a trouble ticket with Verizon? I would like things to work like every previous month I've been on a 2G plan, and I would like to put a stop to whatever is burning through my usage.

Comment: Is this data plan just on your phone, or is this a hotspot/MiFi-type device?

Comment: It's shared between the phone and a hotspot. I realized after posting that an XP VM was autoupdating over the hotspot, which would seem to account for some big downloads, but not 1G... or am I overrespecting XP?